# linked list using only pointers question+problem

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-management, malloc

I face annoying problem I do not quite understand ,
I have pointers of type int *
example code:

```
int* p_Memory_blocks;

int MemoryInit(int num_of_blocks, int block_size) {

    int* head;
    head = NULL;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_of_blocks; i++) {
        
        if ((head = malloc(block_size)) == NULL) {
            printf("allocating memory failed");
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                p_Memory_blocks = head;
                head = *head;
                free(p_Memory_blocks);
            }
            return 1;
        }
        head = &p_Memory_blocks;
        p_Memory_blocks = head;
    }
    return 0;
}

int* MyMalloc() {
    int* return_block = p_Memory_blocks;
    p_Memory_blocks = *p_Memory_blocks;
    return return_block;
}
void MyFree(int* block) {
    *block = p_Memory_blocks;
    p_Memory_blocks = block;
}
```

thats the code for initializing my pool for memory trying to connect the pointer to a linked pointer somehow

basically Im using pointers to build linked pointers

(my assignment is to build a fixed block memory pool allocator , I can only malloc the total amount of block_size * block_amount in bytes ,and I cannot use any more mallocs for any manager , the only thing I have is a global variable of type int * so i wanted to build a linked pointers and return the head to the user and then advance it to the next pointer)

in theory the p_Memory_blocks should advance to the last value because like linked list he is the head currently but the I get 'Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.' and such
if fails after using twice
p_Memory_blocks = *p_Memory_blocks;
,so anyone got an explanation ? or a better way to implement it?

thank you very much !

Ive tried to malloc more memory , and variable types

Comment: A linked list node has two fields: next and value. You're not going to get far with just one field. Until you address this, you are doomed to fail

Comment: Your code is incomplete. Please [edit] your question and copy&paste a [mre]. Your attempt to use the pointers is not a correct implementation of a linked list. You should get warnings from your compiler because of assigning incompatible types. Fix all errors and warnings. If you don't know how to fix them, copy&paste the full error or warning message and ask for

Comment: Not sure any of the *nx = n(x+1) assignments is correct. Additionally, in printf, you are trying to print the memory location the pointer points to, not its value... What are you trying to achieve, exactly? Could you provide an example of the output you would expect?

Comment: Im not allowed to use anything else except a global variable of type int * , which means I cannot use nodes to do linked list , I tried to implement a linked pointers of some sort ,and I came across this problem , I do not understand why its not possible to do

Comment: @AlexBabushin: your code has many issues. It would appear you are misusing pointers.

Comment: the print does not matter , the problem is that the n1 = *n1 works only once , but why?

Comment: If there are problems with the question, fix them by editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

A linked list node has two fields: next and value. You're not going to get far with just one field. Until you address this, you are doomed to fail.

---

Your immediate problem stems from this.

In your loop, `n1` sometimes contains a pointer to the next node, and it sometimes contains a value, and you have no way to tell the two apart.

In technical terms, `n1` will eventually hold `100`, at which point `*n1` results in undefined behaviour.

You need to address the issue that your structure does not contain enough information before you can proceed.

Comment: Ive updated the questions with more code details , it seems like I wasnt clear

Comment: Nah, it was clear. What you now have posted, otoh, doesn't demonstrate the problem. But it's still the same problem. Gotta run